# Bluez mesh api import agent not working on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluez, bluetooth-mesh

What I am trying to do is running the test_mesh script for the bluez mesh api on a raspberry pi 4B. The script is at the following link: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-mesh, and the documentation for the mesh api is here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mesh-api.txt.

I am running the script, and in the menu that is displayed I wrote "join", and I get "Provisioning agent not found". I found that this comes from the `import agent` statement in line 130 of the test_mesh script, which causes an `ImportError`, and the agent is set to `None`. I tried looking into what can cause this error, but there really isn't that much information (or at least I didn't find it).

Sorry if this question is too general, or if it turns out the answer is obvious. I just don't have too much experience with bluetoorth. Any help woud be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to also download the `agent.py` file from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test . The Bluetooth SIG also has some resources that might of interest to you: https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/bluetooth-internet-gateways/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your suggestion worked. Unfortunately I just got to a different error: 
`dbus.connection:Unable to set arguments (dbus.ObjectPath('/example'),b'\x19\x80\xb4\xc6\x06\x0fIo\x86y\xe3\xe5\x8ay\xe5\xc9)according to signature None: <class 'UnicodeError'>: String parameters to be sent over D-Bus must be valid UTF-8 with no noncharacter code points`. 
I don't really think it would be a valid solution to just keep asking with every error I get, and I also believe this error may be caused by a bad setup. Could I please just get some info on setting the api up on RaspberryPi4?